# Bigquery to Redshift data transfer using AWS SCT failing?

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, aws-sct

I am trying to migrate data from Bigquery to Redshift using [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-google-bigquery-to-amazon-redshift-using-aws-schema-conversion-tool-sct/). I followed through and successfully got till "Start the Local Data Migration Task".I had to setup AWS profile to access "Data Migration View(Other)". AWS profile was setup using access key and access secret of an admin user account in AWS.

What am I missing ?However, upon starting the task I keep getting following error:

```
class com.amazon.dmt.model.FileCredentials cannot be cast to class com.amazon.dmt.model.UserCredentials (com.amazon.dmt.model.FileCredentials and com.amazon.dmt.model.UserCredentials are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I tried to check AWS documentation and looked around but this error is not listed anywhere. I cannot seem to understand that, why is type casting from FileCredentials to UserCredentials is being done ?

Anyone faced a similar issue or can point me in right direction please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, I have determined that this is an issue in the 1.0.670 version of SCT. A request has been submitted to correct the issue. In the meantime, to allow you to continue with your project, please revert to AWS-SCT version 1.0.666 using this link. https://d211wdu1froga6.cloudfront.net/builds/1.0/666/Windows/aws-schema-conversion-tool-1.0.zip
You will have to uninstall SCT and the extractor agent then reinstall and configure the previous version(s) as you did before.